# Converting a CURL request into JS Ajax - how to validate?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't have access to my intended URL yet but I have been reading tutorials about how to interface with adobe and the tutorial says the request should be in this format:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://analytics.adobe.io/api/{COMPANYID}/reports \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESSTOKEN}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-api-key: {APIKEY}' \
  -H 'x-proxy-global-company-id: {COMPANYID}' \
  -d '{REQUESTJSON}'
```

I am instead trying to write this as an Ajax request in javascript. I have this code:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://analytics.adobe.io/api/abc/reports",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer {ACCESSTOKEN}",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "x-api-key": "{APIKEY}",
      "x-proxy-global-company-id": "your key",
    },
    data: {json: jsondata},
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm struggling to work out if the javascript I have written is actually achieving the same thing, in other words, if the curl above works, would this javascript code replicate that exactly? Is there any way for me to validate this?

Thank you,

James

Comment: The short answer - it looks ok to me but you should keep in mind that client to server you may run into CORS issues where server to server is fine...

Comment: you're missing the method type.